# Система управления версиями для mac os lion?

Tags: mercurial, mac, контроль-версий

Нужно использовать `Mercurial`. Какая графическая оболочка лучше - `SourceTree`, `MacMercurial`, `MacHg`. Плюс, есть ли документация с примерами по этому ПО, и вообще, о системах контроля версий их применению?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я знаю, по функционалу они почти не различаются друг от друга, так что упор надо делать на удобство использования. Попользуйтесь всеми тремя некоторое время, и сами в конце концов выберите нужное. 
Насчет руководств по отдельным программам - обычно разработчики выкладывают на своих сайтах либо что-то вроде FAQ'a (или Wiki), либо пару скринкастов на тему "Get Started" (я правда, нашел приличную документацию только у [MacHg](http://jasonfharris.com/machg/MacHgHelp/MacHgHelp.html), но, возможно, плохо искал). Обычно, все подобного рода программы построены по одному принципу, так что проблем возникнуть не должно  (ну, на крайний случай можно в справку залезть).
Ну а руководств по  системам контроля версий куча. Да, конечно, большинство на английском, но есть пару хороших ресурсов и на великом и могучем, например:

- [GitHowTo.com](http://githowto.com/) - отличное введение
     в гит для новичков
- [Wiki проекта
     Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RussianTutorial) - так же вполне
     доступно описано

Ну, и конечно, я думаю, если возникнет какой вопрос по мере изучения - можете всегда задавать его на ХешКоде.